# How to use .each() to run a function with a variable, where the variables are stored in an Array

Tags: jquery

I have a function `showCurrent(tab)` that I need run on a number of variables. I'm looking for a way to automate it, so I don't have to do this:

```
showCurrent('tab1');
showCurrent('tab2');
showCurrent('tab3');
```

I've been trying to use $.each() but clearly I'm using it wrong, because it's not working. Here's what I've been trying (and failing):

```
var tabList = ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3"]

$.each( tabList, function(index, value) {
  showCurrent($(this));
});
```

Comment: why not just `showCurrent($(value))`?

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem. Seems like you should use instead a jq method `$.fn.showCurrent()` called like  $('selector').showCurrent();. BTW, are `"tab1", "tab2", "tab3"` IDs or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the $(this) with the 'value' in your loop. that'll automatically call the functions with the values. :)

You might aswell change it to;

showCurrent(tabList[index]);

There are two ways to resolve your problem, 1: by using the parameters from $.each ( index and value )

```
var tabList = ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3"]
$.each( tabList, function(index, value) {
    showCurrent(value);
});
```

But if you want to have a bit more of control of your loop, you can use the second method; the indexer from $.each, then it should be like this;

```
var tabList = ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3"]
$.each( tabList, function(index, value) {
    showCurrent(tabList[index]);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, did you mean like this?

$.each( tabList, function(index, value) {
  showCurrent();
});

Comment: In the showCurrent() add the tabList[index]. the 'index' is a counter, see it as; 1, 2, 3. The tablist is your array, so we're asking for the value on the index; 1, 2, 3. which returns; tab1, tab2, tab3. :) but the .each also has the value, so you can remove the tabList[index]  and make it showCurrent(value);

Comment: It's just usefull to know that you can also retrieve information from an array by just the index. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `value` instead of `$(this)`.

```
var tabList = ["tab1", "tab2", "tab3"]
$.each( tabList, function(index, value) {
    //The function parameter value is tab1, tab2 & tab3.
    //And index is array index number 0, 1 & 2
    showCurrent(value);
});
```

`$(this)` is object, here it returns `Object["t", "a", "b", "1"]`, `Object["t", "a", "b", "2"]` & `Object["t", "a", "b", "3"]`. So you should not use `$(this)`.